# Vertex2 confusion with haskell openGL bindings

Tags: opengl, haskell, vertex

I'm using Haskell openGL bindings to try to make a particle generator. 
I want to store information about a particle in a record where I can then pass in fields and update them when appropriate.

So a position in the record is stored as:

```
data Particle = Particle { pos :: Vertex2 GLfloat }
```

and set like this:

```
Particle { pos = Vertex2 1 (0::GLfloat) }
```

Then I pass in the particle and try to retrieve the values like so:

```
drawParticle :: Particle -> IO ()
drawParticle part = 
    (pos part) >>= \(Vertex2 x y) ->
    print x
```

The error I get:

```
Couldn't match type `Vertex2' with `IO'
Expected type: IO GLfloat
  Actual type: Vertex2 GLfloat
In the return type of a call of `pos'
In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `(pos part)'
In the expression: (pos part) >>= \ (Vertex2 x y) -> print x
```

I'm mildly confused about the data type Vertex2 and why it has to be declared with a single GLfloat instead of two. How would I extract numbers from the data type Vertex2 GLfloat?
(that is how would I extract Vertex2 1 (0::GLfloat) to be x = 1.0, y = 0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- It would be possible to define Vertex2 to take two types, to allow X to have one type and Y another, e.g. `data Vertex2 xtype ytype = Vertex2 xtype ytype`.  However, it's generally a bad idea to have two different types for X and Y so instead it's defined as: `data Vertex2 sametype = Vertex2 sametype sametype` to save problems.
- Since you have explicitly typed the Vertex2 in your declaration for Particle, you don't need to type the expression you list.  Just `Particle { pos = Vertex2 1 0 }` should be enough.  (Or: `Particle (Vertex2 1 0)`).
- You get the compile error because you don't need monadic bind.  `part` has type `Particle`, not `IO Particle`, so you don't need bind to get the value out.  You can write either:

  `drawParticle part = let Vertex2 x y = pos part in print x`

or:

```
drawParticle part = do
    let Vertex2 x y = pos part
    print x
```

(Note the two different forms of let, depending on whether it's in a `do` block; this confused me when I started out.)